# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected TRUNC(SYSDATE)+hour/24

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbctemplate, date-math

I have a query which runs in sql developer as follows.

```
UPDATE TEST_tbl SET FAIL_DT=TRUNC(SYSDATE)+08/24,UPDT_DT=SYSDATE, TXT='failed' WHERE SRC='srctest'
```

when I try to implement the same query in jdbcTemplate with parameter I get the following exception,

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE TEST_tbl SET FAIL_DT=TRUNC(SYSDATE)+?/24, TXT=? WHERE SRC=?",hour,message,srcTable)
```

where the value of hour can be anything between 0-24.

Comment: Maybe cast the `hour` value to an integer

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table, that is maybe setting a last-updated time with an implicit conversion?